# How to resolve being unable to rebase master branch from multiple remotes?

Tags: git, github

I tried to rebase my `master` conflicted. Resolving it manually and adding the files did not work. Both `git rebase --skip` and `git --rebase continue` failed.

Git asked if I forgot to add anything.

All I was able to do was `git rebase --abort`. Also, pushing to github failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my misunderstanding of git remotes. I have two remotes, one on github and one on a private server. So I have two different masters. Trying to rebase the two was prone to failure.

On my local machine, I cloned my private repo and added the github remote `githubrepo`.

I hence did a tracking remote checkout of its master:

```
git checkout --track -b githubmaster githubrepo/master
```

And applied the commits there.

Also, against what I am used to, `origin` didn't point to github, but to my private server, and so I had to:

```
git push githubrepo githubmaster:master
```

Now, development is done in `githubmaster` and into my `origin`, I only merge the changes of `githubmaster`.